Linear Algebra: Least Squares Approximations
There is an equation $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ which we cannot solve. Every vector $\mathbf{b}$ can be split into two parts: the part in the column space is $\mathbf{p}$ and the part in the left null space is $\mathbf{e}$.
There is an equation $A \mathbf{\hat{x}} = \mathbf{b}$ which we can solve. The solution to $A \mathbf{\hat{x}} = \mathbf{b}$ leaves the least possible error ($\mathbf{e}$).
Now the squared length for any $\mathbf{x}$ is: $ \| A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b} \|^2 = \| A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p} \|^2 + \| \mathbf{e} \|^2$. May be it is easy to grasp but I am not able to understand why the squared length for any $\mathbf{x}$ is defined that way?

Suggestion. Write the vector $b$ as the orthogonal sum of  two pieces:  the  vector  $p$ in the range of $A$ that is closest to $b$ and the part $e$ that is orthogonal to the range space.

It's not a definition. It's a theorem that if $u^Tv = 0$, then $|u + v|^2 = |u|^2 + |v|^2$. It's the Pythagorean theorem.

@Kakashi $ u = A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}$ is some vector in the column space of $A$ and $v = \mathbf{e}$ is the vector perpendicular to $u$. But how come $ u + v = A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}$ ?

@DineshKumarBaghel $b = p + e$ so $Ax - b = Ax - p - e$.

@Kakashi So it becomes $u-v$ and not $u+v$. Right?

@DineshKumarBaghel well, you can let $u = Ax - p$, $v = -e$.

@Kakashi Ok! Thanks a lot.
